# tail command not giving correct answer for subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, popen

When running below command through terminal, it is giving correct output, i.e. excluding top head 6 lines, displaying remaining lines of data.out .

```
tail -n +6 data.out
```

But when same command is processing through `subprocess.Popen` as given in below code:

```
fin = open('data.out')
fout = file('data1.out','w')
line = 6
lineno = "-n +" + str(line)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(["tail",lineno], stdin=fin, stdout=fout)
errcode = p2.wait()
fin.close()
fout.close()
```

This is storing last 6 lines of `data.out` in data1.out file, which is incorrect. This is storing output of `tail -n 6 data.out`, not of given and expected `tail -n +6 data.out`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't mix multi-arguments with list arguments

```
lineno = "-n +" + str(line)  # wrong: 2 arguments seen as one
p2 = subprocess.Popen(["tail",lineno], stdin=fin, stdout=fout)
```

you have 2 arguments here, and the `+line` part is probably ignored by `tail`. Instead, just pass one argument per list item:

```
p2 = subprocess.Popen(["tail","-n","+"+str(line)], stdin=fin, stdout=fout)
```

maybe clearer using `format`:

```
p2 = subprocess.Popen(["tail","-n","+{}".format(line)], stdin=fin, stdout=fout)
```